# Docker client container (NextJS 13) and server container (.NET Core 7) setup for development not working

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, next.js, docker-compose

Our team is working on a project using a dockerized NextJS 13 client app and a dockerized .NET Core 7 server app. Both projects are in different GIT Repos, so they have a different docker-compose.yml file. Now I want to set this up for development, but something seems to be not working because on the server we have a GET endpoint for fetching items, the endpoint is `/api/items/all` and when I fetch from the client to `http://server-app/api/items/all` this works. However, we also have a POST endpoint on `/api/item` but when I post to `http://server-app/api/item` this does not work.

The error states: `POST http://server-app/api/item net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` and `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

All containers are on the same network: sever_development_network.

Client Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Client docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  server_development_network:
    external: true

services:
  client-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: client-container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    env_file:
      - ./.env.local
    networks:
      - server_development_network
```

Server Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# Copy solution and project files
COPY *.sln .
// Copy the other folders over
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS final-env
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
```

Server Docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: "3.4"

networks:
  development_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  server-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    container_name: server-container
    image: docker.io/library/server
    ports:
      - "8050:80"
    depends_on:
      - "database"
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=//connection string
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
    networks:
      - development_network

  database:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
    container_name: database
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=//password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - app_data:/var/lib/mssql/data
    networks:
      - development_network
volumes:
  app_data:
```

Docker is still very new for me, please keep that in mind.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: They seem to be different networks: `server_development_network` != `development_network`. Container name resolution will only work inside the same Docker network, otherwise you'd need to use the published ports via `host.docker.internal`

Comment: when i run ```docker network ls``` it lists the ```server_development_network``` and when I do ```docker inspect server_development_network``` it lists all the containers under the container section. So that would mean they all run on the same network, no?

Comment: The NextJS application ultimately runs in the browser, even if its code is being served from a container.  The browser is outside the Docker environment and so it can't resolve the container names as host names.  For a purely local setup, pointing at the backend's published `ports:` `http://localhost:8050/...` should work.

Comment: It does not work, because NextJS SSR renders inside the container, so it has no access to the host localhost. I got it working using ```http://host.docker.internal:8050``` now. Although I strongly feel like I am doing something incorrectly. In my understanding, docker was made to make development easier. This is not easier.